# CUDA 2D block the y dimension isn't changed as expected

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I try to build a 2D block, and store all x,y in a 2d array and turn it back to the host. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

#define N 95

__global__ void add(int *ch) {
  int idx = (blockIdx.x * N) + (blockIdx.y * 2);
  *(ch + idx) = blockIdx.x;
  *(ch + ++idx) = blockIdx.y;
}
int main(void) {

  int h_ch[N*N][2];
  int *dev_ch;

  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ch, sizeof(int[N*N][2]));

  dim3 numBlocks(N,N);


  add << <numBlocks, 1 >> > (dev_ch);

  cudaMemcpy(h_ch, dev_ch, sizeof(int[N*N][2]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i++) {
    printf("%d-%d\n", h_ch[i][0], h_ch[i][1]);
  }

  cudaFree(dev_ch);

  return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, the result should begin from 0-0 and end up to 94-94, and the output should be 95*95=9025 rows, but, I got just around 4500 rows.
I changed my code to see how the x,y are changed, the x is changed between 0 and 94, and it gets repeated 94 times for each number as expected.
However, the y starts from 51 and ends up to 94, it loops 94 times for each number. What is wrong with the y? shouldn't it vary the same as how the x does?

Comment: Can you please show a sample expected output for a smaller value of N (e.g. N = 5)?

Comment: it would be: 0-0,1-0,2-0,3-0,4-0/
0-1,1-1,2-1,3-1,4-1/
0-2,1-2,2-2,3-2,4-2/
0-3,1-3,2-3,3-3,4-3/
0-4,1-4,2-4,3-4,4-4

Answer (score 2):

The indexing calculations in your kernel are incorrect. It should look like this:

```
__global__ void add(int *ch) {
  int idx = (blockIdx.x * 2 * N) + 2 * blockIdx.y;
  *(ch + idx) = blockIdx.x;
  *(ch + ++idx) = blockIdx.y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hint. But, the current issue is range of the y. I just printf the value of y inside of the kernel, and as I explained the result was 51 to 94.

Comment: @Sina: It isn't a hint, it is the correct solution to your problem, and if you test it you will see that your program produces the correct output. The problem with printf is something else altogether.  CUDA has, by default, a limited size output buffer for printf within kernels, and your 95 x 95 case will overflow that buffer. Nothing to do with your core problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the issue got sorted out. Just another question, if I want to have a 2D grid for example 2x2, and each grid contains 95x95 blocks, is this code correct: `dim3 numGrids(2,2); dim3 numBlocks(95,95); add <<<numGrids, numBlocks>>> (dev_ch);` ?